# UIimageView animation is using too much memory

Tags: ipad, animation, uiimageview

I have two uiimageview animations. One on each of two view controllers in a navigation controller.

They have about 10-15 frames each. This is the smallest I can possibly make them.

They seem to be using a hell of a lot of memory though. Especially on `startAnimating`. Is there any way around this?

On my iPad this is causing a memory warning an a leak. I've tried looking into it, and as per an earlier question on here I've been using a lot of memory tools and such and narrowed the issue down to the startAnimating function.

I have read that this is because on startAnimating the imageView puts all the images into memory at this point.

However removing from superview and releasing dosen't seem to have a marked effect on the amount of memory reclaimed.

Is there any way around this? Bar creating a custom OpenGL style animation?

Thanks

Comment: Not really... cut down the amount of frames and optimised the hell out of the images and released everything and anything I possibly could!

Answer (score 0):

Even i use to face same Problem.. I came up with solution by using custom navigation controller. Now i don't see any memory warnings or memory leaks.

Try to implement your own custom navigationController.